# Problem activating feature on child webs

Tags: 2010, feature-activation, feature-receiver

I have a feature that is manually activated. In a feature receiver I also activate the feature on any child SPWebs in existence. I would like some code to run only on the SPWeb where the feature is manually activated.

The code below won't work as I intend because the method "EnsureSourcePublicationList" will get called on all the child webs as well.

How do I call "EnsureSourcePublicationList" on only the SPWeb where the feature is activated via the UI?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPFeature feature = (SPFeature)properties.Feature;
    SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;

    EnsureSourcePublicationList(web);

    foreach (SPWeb childWeb in web.Webs)
    {
        try
        {
            childWeb.Features.Add(feature.DefinitionId, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: handle exception via logging
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running a check on the parent web to see if the feature is activated. Since this is only applying to sub webs and it is in the `FeatureActivated` event, it will already be activated on the parent for you to verify.

## Edit

Code added to check if `web.ParentWeb != null`

```
bool isChild = false;

if (web.ParentWeb != null)
{
    foreach (SPFeature parentFeature in web.ParentWeb.Features)
    {
        if (parentFeature.DefinitionId == feature.DefinitionId)
        {
          isChild = true;
        }
    }
}

if (!isChild)
{
    EnsureSourcePublicationList(web);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you test the code too, because I haven't lol.

Comment: That works, after I added a check to make sure ParentWeb is not null.

Comment: Good call. Thanks for accepting. Glad I could help.